# Does your hostname save on your NIC | centos 7?

Tags: linux, centos, hostname

I recently installed CentOS 7 on a new hard drive with all default settings and when I enter:

```
# hostname
```

I get:

```
SVP
```

But "SVP" is neither in `/etc/hostnames` nor `/etc/hosts` configured.

But I have the default hostname `localhost.localdomain`.

SVP was the machine name of my old windows install but that hard drive wasn't even connected during my CentOS install and isn't connected now so my best guess is that the hostname `SVP` was saved on my NIC and written during my CentOS install. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it more likely that the name comes from the DNS. The machine gets the same IP address from DHCP (because the MAC address is still the same), and CentOS does a reverse lookup on the IP address and gets the old name back from the DNS server.